# Image validation using RegularExpression in HttpPostedFileBase always false in ModelState.IsValid

Tags: c#, asp.net, model-view-controller, nsregularexpression

I have a form with the upload image field using htmlhelper but in controller it always return false using ModelState.IsValid and I don't know what's wrong with my code. Can you help me? Here's my code.

Form.cshtml

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AddonSaveLayout", "Admin", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.AddonLayoutForm.AddonSetup.Id)
    <div class="box box-primary">
        <div class="box-body">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Upload Image </label>
                @Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.AddonLayoutForm.AddonSetup.ImagePath, new { type = "file", @accept = "image/jpg, image/jpeg, image/png" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.AddonLayoutForm.AddonSetup.ImagePath, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="box-footer">
            @Html.ActionLink("Back", "AddonSetup", null, new { @class = "btn btn-warning" })
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="submitAddCatBtn">Save</button>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Model.cs

```
 [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select file.")]
 [RegularExpression(@"([a-zA-Z0-9\s_\\.\-:])+(.png|.jpg|.jpeg)$", ErrorMessage = "Only Image files allowed and should be 5MB or lower.")]
 public HttpPostedFileBase ImagePath { get; set; }
```

Controller.cs

```
if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    string messages = string.Join("; ", ModelState.Values
                                    .SelectMany(x => x.Errors)
                                    .Select(x => x.ErrorMessage));

     var TicketDesc = db.TicketDescriptions.ToList();
     model.AddonLayoutForm.TicketDescriptions = TicketDesc;
     return View("AddonForm", model);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend placing a breakpoint on your controller method and examine your ModelState to find the offending property causing it to result in an Invalid ModelState.

Comment: It was merely an attempt to find the answer, as there isn't a single answer that explains this error for all occurrences.

Comment: I'm still new to stackoverflow and I'm not yet allowed to add comments. It requires rep 50.

Comment: Thinking back to when I was a new developer, I would have appreciated a comment letting me know I can break point and explore the ModelState for the offending property. It seems like a helpful tip to lead them to the answer. But I'll delete it if deemed inappropriate.

Comment: Your edits, though subtle, changed the impression this posts gives me. I now see what is considered a "partial" answer and appreciated on StackOverflow. Maybe it is just the slightly more assertive phrasing. Keep it.

Comment: After reading the documentation you provided, I'll try to improve on how I present information.